# Как в Visual Studio 2005 отлаживать программу с параметрами командной строки?

Tags: visual-c++

Как в Visual Studio 2005 сделать так, чтобы по F5 (запуск программы под отладкой) программа запускалась с заданными аргументами? Программа на С++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, как в 2005 версии, но в 2008 должно делаться так: 
`Project -> имя_твоего_проекта Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Debugging` и справа в окошке будет поле под названием Command Arguments. Туда и вводите аргументы. Должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось!

Answer (score 1):

В параметрах проекта задайте правильные ключи для запуска программы.

[Пример параметров командной строки](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cs8hbt1w.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Не помню, как в 2005, а в 2010 так:

1. Проект -> Свойства
2. Отладка -> Аргументы команды

И пишите те значения в строчку, которые хотите передать при запуске программе.